# Push from remote branch to different remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-refspec

If I want to push the contents from a remote:master to the same remote but a different branch, how can I do this?

With `git push remote.git master:mybranch` I can push the local repo into the second branch

But what I'd like is push not from the local but from the remote

So `remote:master -> remote:branch`

Something like this?

```
git push remote.git 'refs/remotes/master:refs/remotes/mybranch'
```

```
git push remote.git 'refs/heads/master:refs/heads/mybranch'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull actual master into local branch (you can do it to new branch), and push to remote.

Comment: yes, you can also do it on remote repo if you have direct file access to this repo

Comment: just to clarify, I am referring to the same (remote) repo, so what I'd like is to copy the contents of one (remote) branch into another (remote) branch (of the same remote repo)

Comment: That doesn't matter if it is the same repo or not. In git philosophy you must do everything local, and then you can push your changes to remote. If you have file access, you may run git on remote like local repo, and then you can do changes directly. You probably can also do it using [libgit](https://libgit2.org/).

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand what you meant by doing it on remote, great, thanks!!